# Explain jQuery's JSONP and the _ parameter

Tags: javascript, ajax, jquery, jsonp

I understand JSONP and the concept behind it. I also understand that jQuery generates a random callback function like `jQuery93939393_33443434`. But I don't understand, what the `_` parameter is. If I make a JSONP call with

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'GET',
  url: "http://blekko.com/ws/?q=ruby+/json",
  async: false,
  contentType: "application/json",
  dataType: 'jsonp'
});
```

then jQuery generates this url

```
http://blekko.com/ws/?q=ruby+/json&callback=jQuery18209500292707234621_1364031870836&_=1364032979789
```

and inserts the `<script>` tag and generates the callback function `jQuery18209500292707234621_1364031870836`.

But what use has the `_=1364032979789` parameter?

Comment: Is it a timestamp (or other "random" number) to prevent caching?

Comment: yes, timestamp to prevent caching! Great, thx!